# Jquery menu - hide other divs when toggle div

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have created a menu where by clicking a category a div pops up, but I also want other category divs to close when pressing a new one. I'm quite new to Jquery, and even though the first script was easy to write, I'm not sure how to continue. I tried using answers I found here that worked perfectly in the linked jsfiddle, but none of them worked when I tried to use them in my page. 
Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/eCAwiVA/1
Keep in mind I'm trying to do this on a tumblr page.

I have spent hours trying to understand now, I'd be so happy if someone could explain - thank you so much in advance!

Comment: post some code instead of jsbin link, its required here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick JS Bin with the answer to your question: http://jsbin.com/eCAwiVA/15/

Note: If you can, you should only use one `$(document).ready()` function and register all events like I did it.

To the solution: Like you can see, I just use jQuery's `.is()`-method to check if the other `<div>` is visible or not. If it is visible, I just hide it, otherwise I just toggle the `<div>` which is supposed to be opened anyway.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cabout").click(function () {
        if ($("#popsocial").is(":visible")) {
            $("#popsocial").hide();
        }

        $("#popabout").toggle();
    });

    $("#csocial").click(function () {
        if ($("#popabout").is(":visible")) {
            $("#popabout").hide();
        }

        $("#popsocial").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Y if ($("#popabout").is(":visible")) {
             $("#popabout").toggle();
          } instead of $("#popabout").hide() ?

Comment: Thank you for your notice, I edited my answer. This is of course a better solution ;)

Comment: Thanks again! I was also wondering if there is a way to make one of the popups close whenever you click anywhere but the popup? Is this easy to accomplish?

Comment: Thats a little bit more tricky... You would need to add an onclicklistener to the body which closes both `<div>`'s. Then you need to make an onclicklistener for the `<div>`s where you call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the `<div>` from being closed when you click inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this HTML construction, which as previous posts suggested I would advise against, you could check if the siblings of the toggled element are vissible or not. If they are visible you can toggle them as well.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cabout").click(function () {
            $("#popabout").toggle();
            if ($("#popabout").siblings().css('display') != 'none'){
                $("#popabout").siblings().toggle();
            }
        });

        $("#csocial").click(function () {
            $("#popsocial").toggle();
            if ($("#popsocial").siblings().css('display') != 'none'){
                $("#popsocial").siblings().toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cf9E/3/